# Probability using infinite geometric series.

Tags: probability

Six kids, Alex, Bob, Carl, David, Eric, and Frank are playing a game. Before the game starts, each player randomly picks a (not necessarily distinct) number on a fair 6-sided die. Each player takes a turn rolling the die (in the order their names were given), and if it lands on his number he automatically wins. If no kid rolls his number, they start the game over again till someone wins. Compute the probability that David wins.

Here's my train of thought so far:

Let $p = \frac{1}{6}$ and $q = \frac{5}{6}$,

The probability that David wins any particular round $n$, is the probability he rolls his number times the probability that no one who has gone before his has won. Therefore, the probability that David wins is $$\sum_{n=0} ^\infty pq^{6n+3} = \frac{pq^3}{1-q^6} = \frac{(5^2)(6^3)}{6^6-5^6} = \frac{5400}{31031}$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the numerator of the next to last term read $(5^3)(6^2)$?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: Other than that, it looks good!

Comment: Yes, It is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As stated in the comments, this is correct except that the exponents in the numerator of the next to the last term are swapped.